# Excel Random Numbers

Tags: excel, function, csv, random, formatting

I find myself in need of of using two values min,max (comma separated ints) in the same field, and the first represent a value that cannot ever exceed the lowest attainable by the max one.

Is it possible in excel to create a function for such operation?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Post your code so far. What determines "lowest attainable"? Edit your question and provide a few examples.

Comment: Always sample input data and expected output is helpful for visitors.

Comment: I need to create values similar to this:

1,2

3,3

3,5

5,6


Lets assume 1 is min 6 is max and "max" cannot be below whatever appears in "min".

I don't know how to write this function, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,6)
```

in cell A1 & B1, then

```
=MIN(A1:B1)&","&MAX(A1:B1)
```

in your needed cell.

Please share if it works/not.